# PHP Update password script doesnt work

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on a website with a register system. In the userCP you can change your password. I made this script for it but it doesnt work. Can somebody help me? When I change the password it doesnt give an error but it just doesnt update it.

PHP Code:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['updatePassBtn']))
    {
        $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
        $npassword = $_POST['npassword'];
        $rpassword = $_POST['rpassword'];
        if (!empty($cpassword) && !empty($npassword) && !empty($rpassword))
        {
            if ($npassword == $rpassword)
            {
                if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND `password` = '".SHA1($cpassword)."'")))
                {
                    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = '".SHA1($npassword)."' WHERE `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND `ID` = '".$_SESSION['id']."'");
                    echo '<div class="nNote nSuccess hideit"><p><strong style="color:green;">SUCCESS: </strong>Password Has Been Updated</p></div>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<div class="nNote nFailure hideit"><p><strong style="color:red;">FAILURE: </strong>Current Password is incorrect.</p></div>';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<div class="nNote nFailure hideit"><p><strong style="color:red;">FAILURE: </strong>New Passwords Did Not Match.</p></div>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div class="nNote nFailure hideit"><p><strong style="color:red;">FAILURE: </strong>Please fill in all fields</p></div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

My form:

```
<form action="" class="form" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <label></label>
        <input name="cpassword" type="text" value="Current Password" onfocus="this.value = (this.value=='Current Password')? '' : this.value;" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Current Password';}"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label></label>
        <input name="npassword" type="text" value="New Password" onfocus="this.value = (this.value=='New Password')? '' : this.value;" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='New Password';}"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label></label>
        <input name="rpassword" type="text" value="Repeat Password" onfocus="this.value = (this.value=='Repeat Password')? '' : this.value;" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Repeat Password';}"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" name="updatePassBtn"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe a JavaScript Tag?  Not seeing any PHP or SQL. ahh, little better after update.

Comment: **What does it output?**  You've got an `echo` all over the place, so it's got to be outputting *something*.

Comment: It just ouputs that it was successful so I guess the problem is in the sql.

Comment: You really shouldn't be building your SQL strings like that. You should be using prepared statements, and definitely not using my_sql. Are you sure you have all the field names correct? ie: id is not ID?

Comment: Don't just *assume* that `mysql_query` worked.  Make sure to check for errors.  `$query = mysql_query('...'); if($query === FALSE){ die(mysql_error()); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You count the number of rows that match the username and password, but then when you update you also have the condition that it has to match $_SESSION['id'].  If your session doesn't contain the right 'id', then your update could match no rows.

You should check [mysql_affected_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) before reporting that the update was successful.

You should also check that the mysql functions return success (as @RocketHazmat suggests in a comment).  Many return `false` on error.

Comment: Perhaps adding on that this code is horrifically deprecated might benefit OP :)

Comment: @ChrisCooney, that's true, the mysql_* functions are deprecated, but many people must still maintain an existing app coded with the old functions.  I could also comment on dangerous interpolation of variables into SQL strings, but that's not the point of the question either.

Answer (score -1):

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = '".SHA1($npassword)."' WHERE `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND `ID` = '".$_SESSION['id']."'");
```

You have the mysql_query set up but i dont see you executing it

Comment: [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) executes the query.  It doesn't have prepared statements like MySQLi/PDO do.

Comment: It does because I dont use a variable and mysql_query() executes it